# unique route request needs multiple controller laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, routes, middleware

I am working on one laravel project. I am new to laravel.
I have few roles(editor,user,admin) in the system. We don't need multi auth system.
I don't need multi auth for different roles and create prefix based routes accordingly.

 **e.g**

```
www.sitename.com/admin/editprofile, www.sitename.com/editor/editprofile
```

Let's say if all above mentioned roles request for

```
www.sitename.com/editprofile
```

then I want to call individual controller based on role, so I can handle request properly and my code remain clean. I don't want to do all the things in single controller.

When user/role updates profile, different roles have different input fields so it's better to distribute request to individual controller.

Currently, I am using below package for roles and permission which is nice still.
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

**Environments:**

```
Laravel Version: 5.3
DATABASE: Mysql
Server: Apache
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: It might be easier to implement and cleaner with the  `www.sitename.com/admin/editprofile, www.sitename.com/editor/editprofile`. If you only want one route, you will likely have to put all the logic in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to 'listen' on 1 controller method and then redirect to others based on the input. At least with 5.3:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions

Comment: Sorry for late reply. We used common route www.sitename.com/editprofile and common table for all users so we used only one controller. We can use your approach if anybody wants to redirect to other controller based on requirements.